# appending new rows to a Pandas groupby result object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am new to python and I am trying to insert record into group by result object.

I have below dataframe where ID 1 & 2 has SECTION_GROUP as GROUP 1 and 3 & 4 has GROUP 2 but 5 doesn't have any SECTION_GROUP.

| ID | ENTITY_NAME | ENTITY_NAME | SECTION_GROUP | DOC_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dNumber | U220059090 | GROUP 1 | 40 |
| 2 | tDate | 6-Dec-22 | GROUP 1 | 40 |
| 3 | dNumber | U220059090 | GROUP 2 | 40 |
| 4 | tDate | 6-Dec-22 | GROUP 2 | 40 |
| 5 | sCompany | bp | nan | 40 |

I am trying to get result as below into two separate group.

| ID | ENTITY_NAME | ENTITY_NAME | SECTION_GROUP | DOC_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | dNumber | U220059090 | GROUP 1 | 40 |
| 2 | tDate | 6-Dec-22 | GROUP 1 | 40 |
| 5 | sCompany | bp | nan | 40 |

| ID | ENTITY_NAME | ENTITY_NAME | SECTION_GROUP | DOC_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | dNumber | U220059090 | GROUP 2 | 40 |
| 4 | tDate | 6-Dec-22 | GROUP 2 | 40 |
| 5 | sCompany | bp | nan | 40 |

I have tried below but I am only getting result for GROUP 2. I need to access both groups result outside of loop. Any help is really appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv ('sample.csv',encoding= 'unicode_escape',usecols= ['ID','ENTITY_NAME','ENTITY_VALUE','SECTION_GROUP','DOC_ID'])
distDocIds = df["DOC_ID"].unique()


for docId in distDocIds:
    result = df[df.DOC_ID==docId] # all data for specific Id
    grpResult = df[df.DOC_ID==docId].groupby('SECTION_GROUP') # groupby SECTION_GROUP data
    
    for group in grpResult:
        #check in any record present without SECTION_GROUP
        #if present append group with that record
        foundUnion = result[pd.isnull(result.SECTION_GROUP)] 
        if len(foundUnion) > 0:
            foundUnion = foundUnion.append(group[1])
        **#IF I print foundUnion here I am getting proper result as epxected but I want this access foundUnion outside of loop.
        
newdf = foundUnion.copy()
print(newdf)
```

Comment: Empty cell is an empty string or nan value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the empty cell is empty string `''`, you can do:

```py
mask = df['SECTION_GROUP'].eq('')
rest = df[mask]

for _, g in df[~mask].groupby('SECTION_GROUP'):
    g = pd.concat([g, rest])
    print(g)
```

Prints:

```
   ID ENTITY_NAME ENTITY_NAME.1 SECTION_GROUP  DOC_ID
0   1     dNumber    U220059090       GROUP 1      40
1   2       tDate      6-Dec-22       GROUP 1      40
4   5    sCompany            bp                    40

   ID ENTITY_NAME ENTITY_NAME.1 SECTION_GROUP  DOC_ID
2   3     dNumber    U220059090       GROUP 2      40
3   4       tDate      6-Dec-22       GROUP 2      40
4   5    sCompany            bp                    40
```

---

If the empty value is `NaN`:

```py
mask = df['SECTION_GROUP'].isna()
rest = df[mask]

for _, g in df[~mask].groupby('SECTION_GROUP'):
    g = pd.concat([g, rest])
    print(g)
```

Prints:

```
   ID ENTITY_NAME ENTITY_NAME.1 SECTION_GROUP  DOC_ID
0   1     dNumber    U220059090       GROUP 1      40
1   2       tDate      6-Dec-22       GROUP 1      40
4   5    sCompany            bp           NaN      40

   ID ENTITY_NAME ENTITY_NAME.1 SECTION_GROUP  DOC_ID
2   3     dNumber    U220059090       GROUP 2      40
3   4       tDate      6-Dec-22       GROUP 2      40
4   5    sCompany            bp           NaN      40
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. I have made some mistake in question for DOC_ID. I will create new question for the same. I wanted to make one list our to about list for group1 and group2 and apply sort on DOC_ID.

Answer (score 2):

Use a custom [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
m = df['SECTION_GROUP'].notna()
tmp = df[~m]

out = [pd.concat([g, tmp]) for _, g in
       df[m].groupby('SECTION_GROUP')]
```

*NB. Assuming NaNs in the empty cells, else use `m = df['SECTION_GROUP'].ne('')`.*

Output:

```
[         ID ENTITY_NAME ENTITY_NAME.1  SECTION_GROUP  DOC_ID
 1   dNumber  U220059090         GROUP            1.0    40.0
 2     tDate    6-Dec-22         GROUP            1.0    40.0
 5  sCompany          bp            40            NaN     NaN,

          ID ENTITY_NAME ENTITY_NAME.1  SECTION_GROUP  DOC_ID
 3   dNumber  U220059090         GROUP            2.0    40.0
 4     tDate    6-Dec-22         GROUP            2.0    40.0
 5  sCompany          bp            40            NaN     NaN]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use boolean mask:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['SECTION_GROUP'].isin(['GROUP 1', np.nan])]  # or ''
df2 = df.loc[df['SECTION_GROUP'].isin(['GROUP 2', np.nan])]  # or ''
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
   ID ENTITY_NAME ENTITY_NAME.1 SECTION_GROUP  DOC_ID
0   1     dNumber    U220059090       GROUP 1      40
1   2       tDate      6-Dec-22       GROUP 1      40
4   5    sCompany            bp           NaN      40

>>> df2
   ID ENTITY_NAME ENTITY_NAME.1 SECTION_GROUP  DOC_ID
2   3     dNumber    U220059090       GROUP 2      40
3   4       tDate      6-Dec-22       GROUP 2      40
4   5    sCompany            bp           NaN      40
```

For multiple groups:

```
dfs = {g: df[df['SECTION_GROUP'].isin([g, np.nan])]  # or ''
          for g in df['SECTION_GROUP'].dropna().unique()}
print(dfs)

# Output
{'GROUP 1':    ID ENTITY_NAME ENTITY_NAME.1 SECTION_GROUP  DOC_ID
 0   1     dNumber    U220059090       GROUP 1      40
 1   2       tDate      6-Dec-22       GROUP 1      40
 4   5    sCompany            bp           NaN      40,
 'GROUP 2':    ID ENTITY_NAME ENTITY_NAME.1 SECTION_GROUP  DOC_ID
 2   3     dNumber    U220059090       GROUP 2      40
 3   4       tDate      6-Dec-22       GROUP 2      40
 4   5    sCompany            bp           NaN      40}
```